# <html:select> inside <logic:iterate>

Tags: struts, struts-1, struts-html

I have an `itemList` and for each `item`, a dropdown list of ratings is displayed. After user rates each `item` in `itemList`, i want to store those rates in an array. How can I do it? `selectedRate` below is of `Integer` type, and the code failed to solve the problem.

```
<logic:iterate id="item" name="itemList">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <html:select name="aForm" property="selectedRate">
        <html:optionsCollection name="allRates" label="description" value="value" />
      </html:select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `select` option needs to be associated with a specific item.

The easiest way is to use a collection of `Item`s, and give each `Item` a `rating` property. I used an `Integer` for this example.

The `<html:select>` uses array notation, and directly sets each item's rating. *(I'm using a list of rates from the form itself, and a simpler layout; ignore those differences.)*

```
<logic:iterate id="item" name="ratesForm" property="itemList" indexId="i">
  ${item.name}&nbsp;
  <html:select property="itemList[${i}].rating">
    <html:optionsCollection name="ratesForm" property="rates" label="description" value="value" />
  </html:select>
  <br/>
</logic:iterate>
```

The action accesses the item ratings as we'd expect:

```
RatesForm ratesForm = (RatesForm) form;
List<Item> items = ratesForm.getItemList();
for (Item item : items) {
    System.out.println(item.rating);
}
```

---

If the items do not have an associated rating, you'll need to use a map of item id keys and rating values. This is more convoluted; I recommend a collection.

First, the map will be `Map<String, Object>` because of the way indexed properties work. In addition to a normal getter for the map itself, provide indexed methods:

```
private Map<String, Object> itemRatings;

public Map<String, Object> getItemRatings() {
    return itemRatings;
}

public Object getItemRating(String key) {
    return itemRatings.get(key);
}

public void setItemRating(String key, Object val) {
    itemRatings.put(key, val);
}
```

The JSP will be similar, but use `"()"` *instead of* `"[]"` to use the indexed form methods.

```
<logic:iterate id="item" name="ratesForm" property="itemList">
    ${item.name}&nbsp;
      <html:select property="itemRating(${item.id})">
        <html:optionsCollection name="ratesForm" property="rates" label="description" value="value" />
      </html:select>
    <br/>
</logic:iterate>
```

When the form is submitted, the `itemRatings` map will contain string keys representing each item's ID. Both the key and the value will be `String`s, and you'll need to make any conversions to numeric values manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints. I gave it a try and it worked like a charm!